# Codeigniter sql syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Because I codeigniter returns a syntax error?

```
        $handler_feedback = $this->CI->db
            ->select('
                feedback.id as feedback_id,
                feedback.titulo,
                relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.valor
            ')
            ->from('feedback')
            ->join(
                'relacion_feedback_usuario_principal', 
                '
                    relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.feedback_id = feedback.id AND
                    relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.usuario_principal_id = 20
                ', 
                'left'
            )
            ->get();

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

SELECT `feedback`.`id` as feedback_id, `feedback`.`titulo`, `relacion_feedback_usuario_principal`.`valor` FROM (`feedback`) LEFT JOIN `relacion_feedback_usuario_principal` ON `relacion_feedback_usuario_principal`.`feedback_id` = `feedback`.`id` AND

Filename: /dir/file.php

Line Number: 289
```

Mi original query:

```
        SELECT 
            feedback.id as feedback_id,
            feedback.titulo,
            relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.valor
        FROM feedback
        LEFT JOIN relacion_feedback_usuario_principal ON (
            relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.feedback_id = feedback.id AND
            relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.usuario_principal_id = 20
        )
```

Comment: I agree with @ParagTyagi answer, you should better move your condition `relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.usuario_principal_id = 20` to `where` clause. That seems CI removes it from `JOIN ... ON ...` because there is no first table name on other side on condition statement

Answer (score 1):

It should work the way you have written it.
Its as simple as,

```
$this->db->join('B', 'aCol = bCol AND bOtherCol = 0');
$this->db->get('A');
```

Anyways can you try the **other way** (`join` with a `where` clause),

```
$this->db->select('t1.id as feedback_id, t1.titulo, t2.valor');
$this->db->from('feedback as t1');
$this->db->join('relacion_feedback_usuario_principal as t2', 't1.id = t2.feedback_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('t2.usuario_principal_id', 20);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I can not use the conditional as WHERE because I need the values of the fields provided even if they are empty. In your case the first sql query works because "join" these using it with a single line.

Answer (score 0):

```
relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.feedback_id = feedback.id AND
                    relacion_feedback_usuario_principal.usuario_principal_id = 20
```

Do you have a space between `AND` and `relaction_feedback_ususario_principal.usuario_principal_id=20`?

Comment: Have a linux line break (\n) and 4 tabs. Its a normal identation.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to conslusion my code is not bad, it's a bug in codeigniter.